# mysql_query in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-7

I have to integrate an old script in my Laravel 5.5 website.
The problem with it is: there are a lot of "mysql_query" and "mysql_fetch...". All of this is depreciated and I still need to use this script.

Example:

```
$q_delete = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id_bien='".$id_bien[$g]."'";
        $tmp=mysql_query($q_delete);
        while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp)){
            @unlink('../img/' . $res['nom_photo']);
            /*foreach($tab_formats_photos as $format_photo){
                @unlink('../img/' . $format_photo['prefixe'].$res['nom_photo']);
            }*/
        }
```

How can I use this in my laravel project ? Rebuild all this requests with DB or eloquent ?

thx

Comment: Have you set up the model for this yet?

Comment: Yes, you have to convert it into either query builder or eloquent.

Comment: I think I will create a model Photo and a model Bien, my Photos table is "id_photo", "id_bien" and "name_photo".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a photo model then written using Eloquent is:

```
$data = Photo::select('*')->where('id_bien',$id_bien[$g])->get();
```

And same as:

```
$data = DB::table('photos')->select('photos.*')->where('id_bien','=',$id_bien[$g])->get();
```

Check for Laravel query reference document:
[Laravel Query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

Answer (score 0):

Using this query you will get data from photo table and then you can perform action on data.

```
$data = DB::table('photo')->where('id_bien','=',$id_bien[$g])->select('photo.*')->get();
```